# Change the bg color dynamically, instead of using static value

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-2.7, function

```
def raw_dp(value, loop_name, break_point_1, break_point_2, break_point_3, break_point_4, break_point_5, metrics, symbol = ''):

    facts = [(round(item)) for item in value]
    metrics  += '''<tr><th>'''+ loop_name +'''</th>'''
    for dp in facts:
        if dp <= break_point_1:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#229954">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
        elif dp > break_point_1 and dp <= break_point_2:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#ABC878">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
        elif dp > break_point_2 and dp <= break_point_3:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#F9E79F">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
        elif dp > break_point_3 and dp <= break_point_4:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#FBD567">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
        elif dp > break_point_4 and dp <=break_point_5:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#F9C169">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
        else:
            metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#E67C73">' + ' ' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
    metrics += '''</tr>'''
    return metrics
```

I want to change background color of the html cell dynamically instead of using static value which I am defining as breakpoint_1, breakpoint_2...etc or any other way of writing this function elegantly. I am new to python can someone please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

I do not do Python, but I would suggest to implement a case

https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html

```
def switch_demo(argument):
  switcher = {
    0: "229954",
    1: "229954",
    2: "ABC878",
    3: "F9E79F",
    4: "FBD567",
    5: "F9C169"
  }
```

using something like

```
bg = switcher.get(argument,"E67C73")
```

Here you need to make the test into a number from 0 to 5 - as I said I do not do Python, but a dictionary should be a likely solution

If not, then try

```
                                                   bg = "E67C73"
 if   dp <= break_point_1:                         bg = "229954"
 elif dp >  break_point_1 and dp <= break_point_2: bg = "ABC878"
 elif dp >  break_point_2 and dp <= break_point_3: bg = "F9E79F"
 elif dp >  break_point_3 and dp <= break_point_4: bg = "FBD567"
 elif dp >  break_point_4 and dp <= break_point_5: bg = "F9C169"
```

Then have ONE

```
metrics += '<td style = "background-color:#' + bg + '">' +  str(dp)  + symbol + '</td>'
metrics += '''</tr>'''
```

No need for the `+ ' '` since is ignored in HTML. Instead set a cell padding

Comment: How how could you check the condition above, I think so it wont work